# cargar PHP desde JavaScript

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un juego en JavaScript y el resultado, cuando ganamos o perdemos,  lo paso a una base de datos con PHP. Se limita a hacer una consulta update +1 en partidas y +1 en ganadas o perdidas, y dependiendo si ganamos o perdemos es un archivo PHP u otro.

Lo estoy intentando hacer por AJAX pero no me carga el script. Mirad a ver si podéis echarme una mano.

La parte del AJAX:

```
function ganar() {
var enviar = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var relleno = 123;
  var url = 'ganar.php?relleno=' + relleno;

  enviar.open('GET', url, true);
  enviar.send(null);
  alert("HAS PERDIDO");
  window.location.href = "../charmander/perfil.php";
}
/***********************************************************/
```

El PHP:

```
<?php

$nombre=$_SESSION['usuario'];


$base= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=te_la_juegas','root','');

$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");

$sql="UPDATE USUARIOS SET partidas = partidas + 1, partidas_ganas = partidas_ganas + 1
 where nombre like '$nombre' ";
$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

//$resultado->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);

$resultado->execute(array($nombre));

header('Location:http://localhost/TRABAJO_FINAL/registrado/charmander/perfil.php');
exit;

 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo no funciona lo que tienes? ¿Que error/problemas te encuentras?

Comment: Necesitamos más información:
¿Qué te muestra la consola de desarrollo del navegador? ¿Ubicación de cada uno los ficheros? ¿Funciona cuando accedes manualmente al script `ganas.php`?

Comment: En principio tu codigo funciona, lo probe (con mis datos de BB.DD y rutas ) y funciona perfectamente, te recomiendo un repaso de AJAX [http://librosweb.es/libro/ajax/]  . Como apunte diria que la variable `relleno` no la estas recogiendo en el `PHP` y a la funcion de AJAX le faltan secciones para que sea mas funcional.

Comment: Muchas gracias, siento contestar tan tarde. No había manera que funcionase así, incluso le había puesto para los navegadores.Al final lo hice con PHP a pelo.